El frontend de magento 2.4 no carga bien
alguna vez le ha sucedido que por alguna razon no levanta bien el frontend de su ecommerce en magento?.
He levantado varios ecommerce pero estoy en un apuro actualmente y es que se "instala" todo bien pero cuando accedo al fronte no se carga correctamente, cmpile el frontend pero no levanta nada. Si a agluno le ha sucedio espero me puedan dar una mano
